# git: store different stages of a file in the index/working tree after conflict

Tags: git, conflict, git-add

Assume one file is in conflict state with git.

It means that the index contains 3 versions of the file, the previous one, the one from one branch, the one from the other branch.

I would like to checkout version 3 ("theirs") in the working directory, and stage version 2 ("ours") in the index.

Is there a painless way to do that?

Comment: Actually it is 'ours' version (from the current branch you merge into), 'theirs' version (from the branch you are merging), and 'ancestor' version (common ancestor of both branches) - not previous version in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most pain-free way is like this.

```
# Checkout 'their' version from the index into the working tree
git checkout --theirs file

# reset the index to the HEAD version, i.e 'our' branch
git reset HEAD file
```

Fiddling around with the index with the `update-index` plumbing shouldn't be necessary unless you've lost your `HEAD` (so to speak).

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in "adding one version to the index": that would mark the file as solved (meaning no more "ours" or "theirs").
So it needs to be the last step.

Maybe something like:

```
git show :3:<filename> > <filename>.theirs # save the "theirs" version in a tmp file
git show :2:<filename> > <filename>        # display the "ours" version in the working dir 
git add <filename>                         # add it to the index
                                           #  (marking the conflicting file as resolved)
move  <filename>.theirs  <filename>        # erasing the file with the "theirs" version
                                           # in the working directory
```

Not exactly "painless"...

---

To avoid the temporary file, [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski) suggests using **[`git update index`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html)** (a plumbing command) to manipulate directly the index.

```
--replace --cacheinfo <mode> <object> <path>
```

> `--cacheinfo` is used to register a file that is not in the current working directory. This is useful for minimum-checkout merging.
>
> By default, when a file path exists in the index, git update-index refuses an attempt to add `path/file`. Similarly if a file `path/file` exists, a file path cannot be added. With `--replace` flag, existing entries that conflict with the entry being added are automatically removed with warning messages.

Comment: VonC: you got the trick all right: adding destroys the index stages. I had figured out your solution so far! :-) Not painless at all, but thanks anyway! I'm more looking for some git plumbing command that would achieve this without the trouble of storing a temporary file.

Comment: @Olivier: all right, just wait for Jakub or Jefromi or Charles or... anytime now ;)

Comment: You can use low-level [`git update-index`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) to manipulate index: see `--cacheinfo <mode> <object> <path>` (perhaps with `--replace`) and `--force-remove` options.